# AVPlayer class to be used for Multiple View Controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, avplayeritem

I am using AVPlayer item to play live streams (Radio App). Everything seems to be working, however, the entire code is under one View Controller i.e `PlayerViewController : UIViewController.`  Since I will add more functionality to the app and do not want to repeat all the methods being used for AVPlayer. How can I create a `Swift Class` for `AVPlayer` with all required methods and keep using that class instance on multiple pages (future view controllers) of my app?

Here is the code, which loads to `ViewDid Load()`. Functionality like `Remote Commands` will be added to it later on. I don't want to repeat the code for separate view controllers performing the same task.

```
   func configurePlayer(){
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let url = URL(string: station!.url!) else {return}
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)  

    }
```

**Some Other methods to this class will be**

```
func togglePlayer() {
    if player?.rate != 0 {
        player?.pause()
        self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "play.circle"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        player?.play()
        self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(systemName: "stop"), for: .normal)
    }
}

//Method 1{...}
//Method 2 {...}
```

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you are asking here, you want to just create a class that contains all your audio player configuration code and use it across multiple view controllers? as in you would want a singleton? or different instances of that class that might have slight varying configurations?

Comment: Yes, I would like to create a Single Class that contains all the methods and use that class across other VC's. Let's say if I create a new Swift file with `RadioPlayer : AVPlayer`.  I don't know how to refer it in VCs and use it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have your class inherit from AVPlayer since you probably wont be using *all* the features it has to offer so just create a normal class.

Also, this will vary by a lot depending on your use case or implementation so I will just provide a sample for you to experiment with.

```swift
class UniversalAVPlayer {
    
    var player: AVPlayer?
    
    init(url: URL?) {
        configurePlayer(url: url)
        allFeatureConfigs()
    }
    
    func configurePlayer(url: URL?) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                print("AVAudioSession is Active")
                
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let url = url else {return}
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        
    }
    
    func allFeatureConfigs() {
        //add any configurations you want to add in the future here.
    }
    
}
```

and you should create a delegate to help you with methods like your `togglePlayer` method:

```swift
func togglePlayer() {
    if player?.rate != 0 {
        player?.pause()
        self.delegate?.changeImageForPlayStatus(image : UIImage(systemName: "play.circle"))
    } else {
        player?.play()
        self.delegate?.changeImageForPlayStatus(image: UIImage(systemName: "stop"))
    }
}
```

And for example change your background image in your VC when the delegate method is called using the image it provides you.

Since you won't be setting these functions private you will be able to use them from the instance you create:

```swift
let player = UniversalAVPlayer(url: url) //imagine url is an actual URL
//your config methods will run instantly when you create this instance since they are called at initialization

//Call your methods like this when ever you need.
player.togglePlayer()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This clarifies a lot.

Comment: Hi @shadowofarman . I am unable to get the delegate portion. I created a delegate but how can i change the play button's image similar to toggle function. can you please show how will you create the delegate? Also, tapping the play button does not play the player until it is tapped twice (after then works fine) can't figure out. thanks in advance

Comment: For tapping the player problem: It's probably happening cause you have a button inside a collection view or table view, it's because there are two gestures on top of each other, one for taping/selecting cells, one for the button! to solve this set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false` on the button and handle the events using the collection view's `didSelectItemAt` method.

Comment: And for the delegate, what I said in the answer was just an _example_, it varies by a lot depending on your implementation, the answer was a starting point for you. for example you can just change the button image in the function without a delegate if you have access to the button, and if you don't, use delegates to send this trigger to a place where you do have access to the button so you get notified there and change the image accordingly.